# SQL SELECT only a field in a specific column?

Tags: sql

I have a table called Car List: in the table there is a column called Car, another called Shop, and another called Price.

In simple words it tells the price of each car (Mercedes, Renault, Fiat... etc) in the different shops (Shop 1, Shop2, Shop 3).

I am trying to write a query to see the prices of only Mercedes in all the shops...

Below syntax doesnt work.

```
SELECT  Car, Shop, Prices
WHERE Car = Mercedes
FROM Car List
```

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: Please read some basic tutorials first.

Comment: Doesnt seem fair to downvote this one? There is a clear problem, a attempt by the OP, what more is needed?

Comment: @KayNelson - Any basic tutorial will tell you that `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE` is the correct order and string literals should be in quotes. The question (original version) states they have been using SQL less than a day. Do you really want questions where people hack around for a bit. Guess some syntax and stick it up on SO for correction in lieu of actually doing some reading first?

Comment: Since it wasn't mentioned, it is generally not good practice to use field names or tables names that require back ticks to work. So if back ticks are required that is a good sign to rethink your naming.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Car, Shop, Prices 
FROM `Car List`
WHERE Car = 'Mercedes'
```

Depending on your DB engine you need to escape tables names containing spaces differently.

Answer (score 1):

Define "it doesn't work."  Surely there's an error message that's trying to help you?

For example, what is the data type of `Car`?  Based on the attempted comparison, it sounds like it's a string.  In which case the value being compared would need to be wrapped in quotes:

```
SELECT Car, Shop, Prices WHERE Car = 'Mercedes' FROM Car List
```

Otherwise the query will look for a column called "Mercedes" in the table, which doesn't exist.

Also, your clauses are out of order.  The order should be `SELECT FROM WHERE` not `SELECT WHERE FROM` (at least, I've never *seen* the latter used):

```
SELECT Car, Shop, Prices FROM Car List WHERE Car = 'Mercedes'
```

Additionally, your table name has a space in it.  In general it's best to avoid this, but if you *must* use spaces then in order for the database to parse the query you need to tell it that both of those words form a single identifier.  In SQL Server this is done with square brackets:

```
SELECT Car, Shop, Prices FROM [Car List] WHERE Car = 'Mercedes'
```

If you're using another database engine, you may need to use another enclosing standard.  For example, MySQL uses backticks:

```
SELECT Car, Shop, Prices FROM `Car List` WHERE Car = 'Mercedes'
```

Continuing in this regard, it's often good practice to enclose any database object identifier in square brackets just to be explicit and consistent (using whichever identifier your database engine uses):

```
SELECT [Car], [Shop], [Prices] FROM [Car List] WHERE [Car] = 'Mercedes'
```

Comment: Square brackets is TSQL only. The standard is double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Car, Shop, Prices
FROM "Car List"
WHERE UPPER(Car) LIKE '%MERCEDES%'
```

You may need to change double quotes depending on the RDBMS you are using. Also, this solution is slower than the equal solution for several reasons but it is more compatible if your data is messy.